# Personalizar un edittext en android

Tags: java, android

Hay alguna de manera de cambiar el edittext, para que presiones una tecla especifica el edittext cambie y muestre la forma de una fracción para que le ingreses los números?

Algo parecido a como sucede en Mathway, o utiliza otra cosa que no es un edittext.

[image: ...]

Comment: Por favor, añade código con lo que lleves hasta el momento. Es más fácil ayudar si vemos en qué punto estás o los posibles problemas/errores que te estés encontrando.

Comment: Porque no  creas tu propio teclado, tal vez colocando una serie de botones en pantalla que simbolicen el carácter deseado.